# redhat, multipath on cluster node display different result

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I've a cluster with two nodes installed with "RedHat Entreprise Linux Server 5.6"

If I execute "multipath -ll" on them, I do not get the same result.
I've checked within "multipathd -k" with "show paths" and I do not get all paths on server1.

Note that "server1" is the actif node in the cluster.

Please, how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your great help

===============================================

server1root#multipath -ll
mpath2 (3600c0ff000134c3e8d11e44f01000000) dm-2 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][active]
 _ 3:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  [active][ready]
mpath1 (3600c0ff000134c3e6e11e44f01000000) dm-1 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=95M][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][active]
 _ 3:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  [active][ready]
mpath0 (3600c0ff000118c37dc11e44f01000000) dm-0 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 _ 3:0:0:1 sda 8:0   [active][ready]
mpath4 (3600c0ff000134c3e4912e44f01000000) dm-4 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][active]
 _ 3:0:0:5 sde 8:64  [active][ready]
mpath3 (3600c0ff000118c371d12e44f01000000) dm-3 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 _ 3:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  [active][ready]
server1root#

server1
multipathd> show paths
hcil    dev dev_t pri dm_st   chk_st  next_check
3:0:0:1 sda 8:0   50  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
3:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  10  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
3:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  10  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
3:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  50  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
3:0:0:5 sde 8:64  10  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
multipathd>

server2root#multipath -ll
mpath2 (3600c0ff000134c3e8d11e44f01000000) dm-2 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 _ 2:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  [active][ready]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 _ 3:0:0:3 sdh 8:112 [active][ready]
mpath1 (3600c0ff000134c3e6e11e44f01000000) dm-1 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=95M][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 _ 2:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  [active][ready]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 _ 3:0:0:2 sdg 8:96  [active][ready]
mpath0 (3600c0ff000118c37dc11e44f01000000) dm-0 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 _ 3:0:0:1 sdf 8:80  [active][ready]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 _ 2:0:0:1 sda 8:0   [active][ready]
mpath4 (3600c0ff000134c3e4912e44f01000000) dm-4 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 _ 2:0:0:5 sde 8:64  [active][ready]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 _ 3:0:0:5 sdj 8:144 [active][ready]
mpath3 (3600c0ff000118c371d12e44f01000000) dm-3 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 _ 3:0:0:4 sdi 8:128 [active][ready]
_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 _ 2:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  [active][ready]
server2root#

server2
multipathd> show paths
hcil    dev dev_t pri dm_st   chk_st  next_check
2:0:0:1 sda 8:0   10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
2:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
2:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
2:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
2:0:0:5 sde 8:64  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
3:0:0:1 sdf 8:80  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
3:0:0:2 sdg 8:96  10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
3:0:0:3 sdh 8:112 10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
3:0:0:4 sdi 8:128 50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
3:0:0:5 sdj 8:144 10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
multipathd>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, see below for a clean reading:

```
    server1root#multipath -ll
    mpath2 (3600c0ff000134c3e8d11e44f01000000) dm-2 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][active]
     \_ 3:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  [active][ready]
    mpath1 (3600c0ff000134c3e6e11e44f01000000) dm-1 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=95M][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][active]
     \_ 3:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  [active][ready]
    mpath0 (3600c0ff000118c37dc11e44f01000000) dm-0 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
     \_ 3:0:0:1 sda 8:0   [active][ready]
    mpath4 (3600c0ff000134c3e4912e44f01000000) dm-4 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][active]
     \_ 3:0:0:5 sde 8:64  [active][ready]
    mpath3 (3600c0ff000118c371d12e44f01000000) dm-3 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
     \_ 3:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  [active][ready]
    server1root#

    multipathd> show paths
    hcil    dev dev_t pri dm_st   chk_st  next_check
    3:0:0:1 sda 8:0   50  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
    3:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  10  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
    3:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  10  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
    3:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  50  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
    3:0:0:5 sde 8:64  10  [active][ready] XXXXXXXXX. 19/20
    multipathd>


    server2root#multipath -ll
    mpath2 (3600c0ff000134c3e8d11e44f01000000) dm-2 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
     \_ 2:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  [active][ready]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
     \_ 3:0:0:3 sdh 8:112 [active][ready]
    mpath1 (3600c0ff000134c3e6e11e44f01000000) dm-1 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=95M][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
     \_ 2:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  [active][ready]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
     \_ 3:0:0:2 sdg 8:96  [active][ready]
    mpath0 (3600c0ff000118c37dc11e44f01000000) dm-0 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=558G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
     \_ 3:0:0:1 sdf 8:80  [active][ready]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
     \_ 2:0:0:1 sda 8:0   [active][ready]
    mpath4 (3600c0ff000134c3e4912e44f01000000) dm-4 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
     \_ 2:0:0:5 sde 8:64  [active][ready]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
     \_ 3:0:0:5 sdj 8:144 [active][ready]
    mpath3 (3600c0ff000118c371d12e44f01000000) dm-3 HP,P2000 G3 FC
    [size=279G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
     \_ 3:0:0:4 sdi 8:128 [active][ready]
    \_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
     \_ 2:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  [active][ready]
    server2root#

    multipathd> show paths
    hcil    dev dev_t pri dm_st   chk_st  next_check
    2:0:0:1 sda 8:0   10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    2:0:0:2 sdb 8:16  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    2:0:0:3 sdc 8:32  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    2:0:0:4 sdd 8:48  10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    2:0:0:5 sde 8:64  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    3:0:0:1 sdf 8:80  50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    3:0:0:2 sdg 8:96  10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    3:0:0:3 sdh 8:112 10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    3:0:0:4 sdi 8:128 50  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    3:0:0:5 sdj 8:144 10  [active][ready] XXX....... 7/20
    multipathd>
```